How to access the first url putted in the url bar in Angular 16?
i am using angular v16 and i have an email sent by the backend that has a url that redirect the user to the appropriate page , if the user is not authenticated it will redirect him to the sign in page then to the dashboard , my problem is i want the user will be redirected to the url provided in the email .
i have tried access the url using router.url but it returns / for the first time.
these are the routes :
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('./features/dashboard/dashboard.module').then((m) => m.DashboardModule), canActivate: [SignedInGuard ]  },
  { path: 'requests', loadChildren: () => import('./features/request/request.module').then((m) => m.RequestModule), data: { animation: 'dashboard' }, canActivate: [SignedInGuard ] },
  { path: 'settings', loadChildren: () => import('./features/settings/settings.module').then((m) => m.SettingsModule), data: { animation: 'settings' }, canActivate: [SignedInGuard , TrainingManagerGuard , TrainingAgentGuard , ManagerGuard] },
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('./features/sign-in/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule), data: { animation: 'auth' } },
  { path: 'access', component: AppAccessdeniedComponent  },
  { path: 'notfound', component: AppNotfoundComponent , canActivate: [SignedInGuard ] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/notfound'  },
];

the sign in guard :
export class SignedInGuard  implements CanActivate {
  readonly #authService = inject(AuthService);

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return defer(() => {
      if (!this.#authService.isLoggedIn() && !this.#authService.isLoadingSilentAuth()) {
        return this.#authService.dispatchSilentAuth$().pipe(
          switchMap(() => {
            if (!this.#authService.isLoggedIn() && !this.#authService.isLoadingSilentAuth()) {
              return of(false);
            }
            return of(true);
          })
        );
      }
      return of(true);

    });
  }

}

the user will be redirected in authService , the constructor :
  constructor() {
    super();
    if (environment.int){
      if (this.containsJWT()) {
        this.dispatchSignInJWT();
      }
      this.dispatchSetNewPassword();
      this.dispatchIsErrorSignIn();
      this.dispatchIsErrorSetPassword();
      this.dispatchSignInCredentials();
      this.dispatchSignInSSO();
    }
    if (!environment.int){
      this.dispatchSignInSSO();
      this.signInWithJWT$.next();
    }
  }


here as you can see there are a lot of dispatches that will be triggered from OnInit and for exemple the sso dispatch method :

  dispatchSignInSSO() {
    let me: UserPrivateDTO;
    this.signInWithSSO$
      .pipe(
        tap({
          next: () => this.#state.update((state) => ({ ...state, isLoadingSSOAuth: true })),
        }),
        switchMap((userCredentials) =>
          this.signInSSO().pipe(
            catchError(() => {
              if (environment.int){
                this.#state.update((state) => ({
                  ...state,
                  isLoadingSSOAuth: false,
                }));
                this.messageService.add({ severity: 'warn', summary: 'Warning', detail: 'SSO login failed, Redirecting to Login Page.' });
                this.redirectSignIn();
                return EMPTY;
              }else {
                // Handle error
                this.redirectAccessDenied();
                this.#state.update((state) => ({
                  ...state,
                  isErrorSignIn: true,
                  isLoadingSSOAuth: false,
                }));
                return EMPTY;
              }
            }),
          ),
        ),
        takeUntilDestroyed(),
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (user) => {
          this.sucessLogging(user);
          this.redirectDashboard();
          // Info message
          this.displayStandardMessage(MessageType.SignedIn);

        },
      });
  }

so here instead of redirecting to the dashboard using this.redirectDashboard(); i want  to catch the url before the the sign in guard then redirect to it here

On the guard, you could capture the original URL, using location.pathname (preferred) or location.href
export class SignedInGuard  implements CanActivate {
  readonly #authService = inject(AuthService);

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    #authService.lastUrl = location.pathname; // <- changed here!
    return defer(() => {
      if (!this.#authService.isLoggedIn() && !this.#authService.isLoadingSilentAuth()) {
        return this.#authService.dispatchSilentAuth$().pipe(
          switchMap(() => {
            if (!this.#authService.isLoggedIn() && !this.#authService.isLoadingSilentAuth()) {
              return of(false);
            }
            return of(true);
          })
        );
      }
      return of(true);

    });
  }

}


location.pathname also returns / , but location.href is working fine , Thank you
